# privileged docker container cannot drop capabilities?

Tags: docker, systemd, linux-capabilities

I'm running this

```
docker run --rm --name mydocker --privileged \
    -v /sys:/sys:ro \
    -v /dev:/dev \
    --stop-signal=SIGRTMIN+3 \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -p 5005:5005 \
    -p 8443:8443 \
    --net=host \
    --cap-drop=SYS_BOOT \
    /usr/sbin/init
```

which should run systemd as init and drop SYS_BOOT capability from it. This is required for a clean shutdown of the container. When run as above, it does run systemd init as pid 1, but the capability is not dropped:

```
[root@FK8CDFA9A82A9E7-A /]# cat /proc/1/status  | grep Cap  
CapInh: 0000003fffffffff
CapPrm: 0000003fffffffff
CapEff: 0000003fffffffff
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

when SYS_BOOT capability is dropped, it should look like this:

```
CapInh: 0000003fffbfffff
CapPrm: 0000003fffbfffff
CapEff: 0000003fffbfffff
CapBnd: 0000003fffbfffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? Docker version:

Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   34a2ead
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   34a2ead
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot drop capabilities when --privileged is specified.  That seems like a weakness.  Here is the relevant code: [Docker CE Linux OCI](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/5338e5013ab17a326132ebf813fcdc9d7211cbc8/components/engine/daemon/oci_linux.go)

```
if c.HostConfig.Privileged {
    caplist = caps.GetAllCapabilities()
} else {
    caplist, err = caps.TweakCapabilities(s.Process.Capabilities.Effective, c.HostConfig.CapAdd, c.HostConfig.CapDrop)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: that does seem like a weakness. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to run a docker-daemon inside a container? If it is just for controlling other services then the [docker-systemctl-replacement script](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) would be a far easier option.